# How to pass Javascript Object from Java to Javascript using Nashorn

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn, scriptengine

I have a JavaScript object in String form (actually coming from database) which I need to pass to a Javascript function using Nashorn (Java 8). The Engine treats the parameter passed as a string in javascript. I want it to identify it as a Javascript object.

Below is the code snippet:

```
String script = "function genData(dataModel) { return 'hello world '+ dataModel.url.value + ' done'; }";  

//"{url : {value : "abc.com",type  : "string"},layout : {value : "",type  : "string"}}";  

String dataModel = "{url : {value : \"abc.com\",type  : \"string\"},layout : {value : \"\",type  : \"string\"}}";

ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
Invocable inv = (Invocable) engine;
result = inv.invokeFunction("genData", dataModel);
```

The error I get is:
   javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot read property "value" from undefined in  at line number 1

Comment: your dataModel is not a valid string literal....

Comment: Well the idea was to show how the javascript object looks like and make it less cryptic. I have moved it as a comment and escaped the string if that helps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could convert dataModel string as JSON first - either in the function itself or elsewhere and then pass it.

Example:

```
String dataModel = ...;
// convert the string as a JSON object
engine.put("dataModel", dataModel);
JSObject obj = (JSObject)engine.eval("JSON.parse(dataModel)");
...
// dataModel is a script object - as it is a result of JSON.parse
// pass it as parameter for genData
inv.invokeFunction("genData", obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

If your dataModel is a simple Java `Map` then you can pass it to `invokeFunction` directly as a parameter. For more advanced uses your parameter should implement the `Bindings` interface.

To make this easier I wrote a library called [json](https://github.com/ajermakovics/json):

[Example](https://github.com/ajermakovics/json/blob/master/src/test/java/org/andrejs/json/JsonScriptingTest.java#L27):

```
    Json j = new Json("a", 5);
    Double result = (Double) eng.eval("a+1", j);
```